# Icon to represent a music mix?

Tags: icon

I'm building a music application which can create a mix of songs to play for you. What icon can I use to represent this feature?

Comment: ,,,,egg beater.

Comment: Post that as an answer to add to the list more formally.

Answer (score 2):

How about a music note or a music CD made out of puzzle pieces?

Answer (score 2):

I really like this icon for *Simple Playlist App* on the iTunes store:

[image: Very literal playlist icon]

Alternatively, you could go with something more "mix" related:

[image: Shuffle icon]

Comment: I thought of the shuffle icon but decided against it as it could be confused with the other common feature, shuffle.

Comment: You could combine the music note and the list the opposite way (ie. 1/4 note instead of 1/8) and have the bars coming from it that way. But this might be a UI question rather than visd question...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you would like something like this one -

[image]

Comment: That's a rather complicated icon, but perhaps simply a turntable would be good.

Comment: I definitely like the idea of a [**turntable**](http://depositphotos.com/8820846/stock-illustration-Vector-illustration-of-isolated-turntable-icon.html), much easier to made into a simple shape